# Auto-match/suggest similar columns between two db tables using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create a javaScript program to find similar columns between two Database Tables.

e.g.

`Table1` has `Emp_Name, Emp_Id, Emp_Dept` while `Table2` has `Name,Id,Department`

Are there any readily available libraries in JavaScript which could help with this?

I have gone through these links:

https://dzone.com/articles/a-simple-machine-learning-project-in-javascript

https://blog.bitsrc.io/11-javascript-machine-learning-libraries-to-use-in-your-app-c49772cca46c

But now I am even more confused as some of these libraries dont exactly look like a perfect match.

Answer (score 0):

you can read from information schema to populate all columns name of the every tables and then proceed to use a string distance / similarity algorithm to find similar columns name between the two table.

the most popular one is levenshtein distance algorithm but there are many other as well
eg: jaccard / hamming / cosine similarity. you can select one and do trial & error to see which one perform the best in your use cases.

Comment: Thanks @Tuan Anh Tran, However are there any javascript package which implement these so that I can have a look?

Answer (score 0):

You can look for string-similarity nodeJS plugin. It's easy to use and better than levenshtein.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-similarity

Comment: cool! I also search a bit more based on @Tuan Anh Tran  and found this :https://www.npmjs.com/package/jaro-winkler.  By the way, any package which would do it based on ML? I mean If I get a better match between "Name" and "Last_Name"  instead of "Name" and "First_Name". However , I want the system to treat   "Name" and "First_Name". as better match going forward instead of calculated one based on above algos, is there a library for this kind of requirement?

Comment: you have to search for libraries that based over statistical model to train your models according to your needs. I used one but I forgot its name yet.